# FFMEPG livestreaming chunks 404 issues

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

this is my FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg \
-re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i rtmp://<> \
-flags +global_header -r 30000/1001 \
-filter_complex "scale=1280x720" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:v libx264 \
-b:v:0 3000K -maxrate:v:0 3000K -bufsize:v:0 3000K/2 \
-g:v 30 -keyint_min:v 30 -sc_threshold:v 0 \
-color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 \
-c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 96k \
-map 0:v:0 \
-map 0:a:0 \
-preset ultrafast \
-tune zerolatency \
-adaptation_sets 'id=0,seg_duration=2.002,streams=v id=1,seg_duration=2.002,streams=a' \
-use_timeline 0 \
-streaming 1 \
-http_user_agent Akamai_Broadcaster_v1.0 \
-http_persistent 1 \
-target-latency 10 \
-media_seg_name $timestamp'/chunk-stream_$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$' \
-init_seg_name $timestamp'/init-stream_$RepresentationID$.$ext$' \
-f dash \
/<event>/out.mpd
```

Dash Mpd plays correctly.

BUT,
I found out some of the m4s chunks go to 404.
CPU of 8GB -> used only 12%.
and we found out that some of the m4s did not generate and some are generating late.
Analysis based on the timestamp of the file creation.

please help me. Am I doing something wrong here?